# Open google maps v2 in current location

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have been trying to make my map fragment open in user's current location, but I don't know what to do... I've tried a lot of things i have been searching in many websites, but I can only center the current location when pressing the myLocationButton.

My MapFragment.java:

```
    package com.example.alex.testing_map;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


 public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{


private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, viewGroup, false);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mapView, fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } else {
        }
    }

    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);



    LatLng p1 = new LatLng(41.39355, 2.15473);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p1).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointer_bici1)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(p1, 18));


}

}
```

For the moment the map opens in the point p1.

Thanks a lot for advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set onMyLocationChangeListener to your map.

Instead of

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(p1, 18));
```

use this:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 18);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }
});
```

or, in Kotlin, use:

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener { location ->
    val cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 18f)
    mMap.animateCamera(cu)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day!! It works nice, but I get a message (not an error) that says that onMyLocationChangeListener is deprecated, any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: as it is written here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener
you should now use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html

Comment: In Kotlin I'm experiencing an warning: `'setOnMyLocationChangeListener(/*...*/): Unit' Unit is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`. Does anyone knows how to fix that?